Google ReCaptcha Issue with custom field in checkout
I have Magento version 2.4.4, in the offline payment, I have added the custom field for the purchase order payment method. Now, the value is saved and the order is placed if we disable the Google Recaptcha, but the same code is not working if we enable Google Recaptcha. Below is my code for saving the value.

event.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="save_po_payable_email" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SavePoPayableEmail" />
    </event>
</config>


Here is my Observer File SavePoPayableEmail.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Zend_Log;
use Zend_Log_Writer_Stream;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class SavePoPayableEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $cart;
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize $serialize,
        \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver $inputParamsResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_serialize = $serialize;
        $this->inputParamsResolver = $inputParamsResolver;
        $this->_state = $state;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $inputParams = $this->inputParamsResolver->resolve();
            if ($this->_state->getAreaCode() != \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
                foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
                    if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
                        $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
                        $paymentOrder = $order->getPayment();
                        $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder();
                        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
                        $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();
                        $method = $paymentQuote->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
                        if ($method == Purchaseorder::PAYMENT_METHOD_PURCHASEORDER_CODE) {
                            if (isset($paymentData['po_payable_email'])) {
                                $paymentQuote->setData('po_payable_email', $paymentData['po_payable_email']);
                                $paymentOrder->setData('po_payable_email', $paymentData['po_payable_email']);
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical('Exception'.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

And from this line

$inputParams = $this->inputParamsResolver->resolve();

I got below error

2024-05-07T11:13:45+00:00 INFO (6): ExceptionReCaptcha validation
failed, please try again

Please let me know, if anyone has face this type of issue.
Thanks in advance !!!
